# How to solve $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}(\cos x+\sin x)^n \; dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate the following integral $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos x+\sin x)^n\ dx=?$$

such that $n\in \mathbb N$

my work:

i thought of using binomial expansion of $(\sin x+\cos x)^n$ but it gives $n+1$ terms which is difficult to integrate. then i thought of substituion

let $\sin x+\cos x=u\implies (\cos x-\sin x)dx=du$ which gives $$dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$
$$\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{0}u^n\frac{du}{\sqrt2\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{0}u^n(1-u^2)^{-1/2}$$
if i assume $u=\cos\theta$ will it work?

i don't see above integration is solvable with this substitution. can someone help me solve this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without substitution 
$$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}(\cos x+\sin x)^n\ dx$$
$$=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\left(\sqrt2\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)^n\ dx$$
$$=2^{n/2}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\sin^n\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\ dx$$
Let $x+\frac{\pi}{4}=t\implies dx=dt$
$$=2^{n/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^n\left(t\right)\ dt$$
Using Beta function, 
$$=2^{n/2}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{2\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}$$
$$=2^{\frac {n-2}{2}}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick:

$$\cos x + \sin x = \sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) $$

$$= \sqrt{2}(\cos x \sin(\pi/4) + \sin x \cos(\pi/4) = \sin (x+\pi/4).$$

So your integral becomes

$$(\sqrt{2})^n\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \sin^n (x+\pi/4) \; dx = 
(\sqrt{2})^n\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n u \; du.$$

We have reduction formulae for this last one.